How to remove hinge pin on BOTTOM hinge of door?
I have a solid wood front door, heavy, and it sticks pretty badly. I thought I'd try bending the hinge with a "Knuckle Bender" tool.  But you have to be able to remove the hinge pin from the hinge.  The hinge I need to bend is the bottom hinge on the door.  But I can't get the pin out.  The Knuckle Bender comes with a pin removal tool but the hinge is too low to the floor (maybe 7") to get any kind of swing on a hammer to dislodge it.  My only chance was to hit the tool with the side of the hammer and that's not enough force to get it to move more than a few thousandths of an inch.  How could I get the pin out in such a situation?

Have you tried lubricating the hinge before bending it.

Well, I'm not sure I can get the oil in. the pin is too tight.

bottle jack the pin out, but what are you doing once the pin is out?  You can replace hinges it just takes a screwdriver.  Are you sure it's the hinge and not the frame?

Just to say that some doors are problems because of seasonal movement/heaving. (And not a fan of hinge bending generally.)

Most hinges are screwed on to the door and frame. Just a wild idea but maybe unscrewing the hinge will help.
Hinges not adjusted right might cause door sticking, but there are other reasons also, and bending hinges should be last choice, not first.
Find the reason for sticking first, then can fix it.
Sometimes it is just loose hinge screws that can be fix with longer screws(most common/easy fix reason).

Well, the hinges are well-screwed in, but I take your point. That is why I put the "Knuckle Bender" away.  It is a job for someone more skilled than I. And looking at the door more carefully, it is clear that it has been a problem for the previous owners as well.

@SteveCohen  If the hinges are tight, making sure the door and door frame are square is usually the next.  Top right corner to bottom left, top left to bottom right.

@SteveCohen are you unable to remove some screws?
